# I keep getting a 'kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException' when trying to create a mapView react-native UI Component in Kotlin

Tags: react-native, kotlin, arcgis, react-native-ui-components

I am trying to create a react-native UI component, using Kotlin on the Android side.  I set up the project using Bob, "https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob", then customized the ViewManager, Package, and created a View.

The component is using the ArcGIS SDK for Kotlin, trying to set up a MapView that would ideally be used as the UI component in my react-native app. "https://developers.arcgis.com/kotlin/api-reference/arcgis-maps-kotlin/com.arcgismaps.mapping.view/-map-view/index.html"

I used some examples I found online to help build this, but they are a little outdated.  The problem comes when I try to build, it throws the error described below.

Here is the code:

DisplayMapBobView:

```
package com.displaymapbob

import android.content.Context
import android.view.View
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.ArcGISMap
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.MapView
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.BasemapStyle
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.Viewpoint
import com.arcgismaps.ApiKey
import com.arcgismaps.ArcGISEnvironment
import com.facebook.react.bridge.LifecycleEventListener
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext

class DisplayMapBobView(context: Context) : LinearLayout(context), LifecycleEventListener {
  var mapView: MapView

  init {
    var rootView: View = inflate(context.applicationContext, R.layout.display_map_bob_view, this)
    mapView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.agsMapView)
    if (context is ReactContext) {
      context.addLifecycleEventListener(this)
    }
    setApiKey()
    setUpMap()
  }

  fun setUpMap() {
    val map = ArcGISMap(BasemapStyle.ArcGISTopographic)
    // set the map to be displayed in the layout's MapView
    mapView.map = map
    mapView.setViewpoint(Viewpoint(34.0270, -118.8050, 72000.0))
    }

  fun setApiKey() {
    // It is not best practice to store API keys in source code. We have you insert one here
    // to streamline this tutorial.
    ArcGISEnvironment.apiKey = ApiKey.create("HIDDEN")

  }

  override fun onHostResume() {
  }

  override fun onHostPause() {
  }

  override fun onHostDestroy() {
  }
}
```

DisplayMapBobViewManager:

```
package com.displaymapbob

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.View
import com.arcgismaps.ApiKey
import com.arcgismaps.ArcGISEnvironment
import com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.MapView
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp


class DisplayMapBobViewManager : SimpleViewManager<DisplayMapBobView>() {

  override fun getName() = "DisplayMapBobView"

  override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext) =
    DisplayMapBobView(reactContext)
}
```

DisplayMapBobPackage:

```
package com.displaymapbob

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager


class DisplayMapBobPackage : ReactPackage {
  override fun createNativeModules(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<NativeModule> {
    return emptyList()
  }

  override fun createViewManagers(reactContext: ReactApplicationContext): List<ViewManager<*, *>> {
    return listOf(DisplayMapBobViewManager())
  }
}
```

display_map_bob_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.MapView
    android:id="@+id/agsMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

After setting up the initial project and running it, I saw the dummy component that was created by default, but after I added code for my mapview component, it fails to build giving the below error.  I am not exactly sure where to go from here, I have messed around with initializing a lifecycle but to be honest, I am new to Android development and Kotlin, so this was proving futile.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.displaymapbobexample, PID: 12413
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property lifeCycleOwner has not been initialized
        at com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.GeoView.getLifeCycleOwner$api_release(GeoView.kt:100)
        at com.arcgismaps.mapping.view.GeoView$RenderingThread.onSurfaceTextureAvailable(GeoView.kt:1315)
        at android.view.TextureView.getTextureLayer(TextureView.java:390)
        at android.view.TextureView.draw(TextureView.java:339)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactRootView.dispatchDraw(ReactRootView.java:297)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19073)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19935)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20210)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:780)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19082)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:801)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3311)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3115)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2484)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Turn the main activity into a singleton and register the map view as a lifecycle observer in your `setUpMap()` method:

```kotlin
MainActivity.getInstance().lifecycle.addObserver(mapView)
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843507/flutter-arcgis-map-view-as-a-platform-view-crashes-on-android/77103330#77103330) for more information.